# Why was this question closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

[This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/470934/scam-or-legit-high-voltage-capacitor-manufacturing/) is from my perspective, a perfectly reasonable one.

The OP does not appear to be asking about a *particular product or where to buy*, but rather if a source of supply they have found (which claims component performance that does not seem reasonable) is **truly legitimate** (we think the answer is *no*).

To answer this question needs quite a lot of experience and is a question I would **encourage** as it illuminates the somewhat shadier side of the electronics supply chain *which is definitely a subject that falls within the remit of valid questions* from my perspective.

Based on Dim's comment, if a simple word like 'price' is mentioned and causes a closure, we could do it with a bot; I would expect mods to exercise a bit of critical thinking on this.

Comment: For some, a question that includes the word "price" automatically goes to the shopping question bin, whatever is actually asked. Yep, that bin is rather huge.

Comment: Agreed, perfectly reasonable question, with some good answers. The answers themselves show this was not a shopping question so no idea why this mod decided to take matters into their own hands and close it

Comment: @MCG because said mod is ban happy.

Comment: Any question trying to make comparisons between a legitimate device (one with a PDF data sheet and made by a recognized manufacturer OR touted through a reputable dealer or both) and a component with none (or few) of the above is missing the point - this makes it a shopping question to me.

Answer (score -1):

Let me paraphrase the question:

I don't like the price at distributor X

Does distributor Y look like it's legit.

IMO this is about shopping and the question would be much better served on the chat as prices and distributors change.

(I did not moderate the original question)

Comment: It is more like "Are any of the distributors selling at such low prices legit?". And that makes a lot of difference.

Comment: I don't really agree with the paraphrase.  The way I read it is that while he was in the process of looking for a cheaper supplier he encountered one most likely too good to be true and was asking wither they could be for real.  The primary question was not about the caps, but about the "supplier" of the caps, not shopping in my mind.